# Red and Blue Tiles Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Q. A bag contains red and blue tiles. Each tile has a number from the set $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ written on it. I want to arrange $6$ of these tiles in a row, so that the numbers on any three consecutive tiles sum to $0$. In how many ways can this be done, assuming that there are an unlimited number of tiles for any color and number combination?

I started by noting there are $6$ ways to make the sum equal to $0.$ We have an unlimited supply of tiles, so $\{0, 0, 0\}$ would count. Each of the six tiles can be either blue or red.

Comment: That's pretty much it, there are $ 6 \times 2^6$ ways.

Comment: @CalvinLin ...seven, actually? The all-zero row?

Comment: Ah yes, i missed the all 0 row, so should be $7 \times 2^6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you fix the first three tiles, which may be $0,0,0$ or $0,1,-1$ in any order, the last three tiles are completely determined by the sum-to-zero requirement. There are $7$ ways to choose the first three tiles – one from $0,0,0$ and six from $0,1,-1$. Them for each complete line, each tile may be red or blue without restrictions, so we multiply $7$ by $2^6=64$ to get the final answer of $448$ arrangements.